# String Template Group File can use resource?

Tags: java, antlr4, stringtemplate-4

On a java project using Antlr4 and String Template 4 can I get a STGroupFile from a resource contained in project's jar?

I made it works using the absolute path, like

```
STGroup gd = new STGroupFile("D:\\templates\\bbx.stg");
```

But I would like to have the .stg file inside the jar.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to access a file within any jar file in the class path by using a relative path syntax:

```
STGroup group = new STGroupFile("templates/bbx.stg");
```

Comment: Pretty obvious, I think! Thanks a lot for your answer, Sam.